# Android App installs not logged in Insights

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-insights

We have an Android App and an iOS App setup under the same Facebook App ID. We use Facebook Login and the relevant SDK's for both iOS and Android and to our knowledge all the correct settings are being used in the developer control panel.

However, our Android app installs are not being displayed in the "Mobile App Installations" insights page, but the iOS installs are being logged.

Does anyone know if there's something special we need to do in order to report the Android app installs, or a setting we have missed that will allow us to see / collect this data?

Comment: Did you follow all of the steps in the documentation? there's a few that may be easy to forget, including if you're using ProGuard there are exceptions you need to add

Comment: Same problem. Do you figure out why Android app does not show in Mobile App Installs but iOS does?

Comment: I have the problem too. Do you find the solution ?